# AWS DataBrew auto-formats XLSX DateTime column to string java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=... (GregorianCalendar) how do I format back in recipe?

Tags: amazon-web-services, xlsx, datetime-format, gregorian-calendar, aws-databrew

I am using AWS Glue DataBrew and have a .XLSX Dataset with a DateTime column.

E.g. Name=Fred, Ticket Number=1234, Departure Date=11/11/2021

When AWS Glue DataBrew opens up the Dataset in Project view, the Departure Date becomes a GregorianCalendar string.

E.g.

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=?,YEAR=2021,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=11,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=?,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=1,HOUR=10,HOUR_OF_DAY=22,MINUTE=30,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]
```

I am trying to covert this string back to a DateTime value such as `2021-11-11 22:30:00`.

All DataBrew built-in conversions I have tried turn the column into null.

Answer (score 1):

Primary reason why you are seeing the string representation of the "Departure Date" column values in DataBrew is because there is at least one cell with string value in it.

If it is possible for you, can you open this excel file and remove or fix one of more such occurrences and try to use this updated file with DataBrew?

Comment: This makes sense - unfortunately I am trying to automate DataBrew for exactly that task - to prepare the data for consumption downstream in Redshift. So the original external raw files are automatically received by email and stored in S3, then pulled into the recipe for cleaning. I was hoping to not have to add a pre-cleaning, data preparation step!

Comment: @jhd - Is it possible that you can fix the tool or software that is preparing the XLSX files to not have any string in the column with date? I think that probably will fix this issue? Or may be other option is to convert that column to string in the XLSX itself and that probably should get read as string in Databrew as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem. I solved it with work around using filter on column and regex

For Year use: (\d{4})
and so on